# Maven - run integration and unit tests

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I have 2 sets of tests defined in Maven - integration-test and test.

If I run `maven test` - my tests run

If I run `maven integration-test` - both run

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <configuration>
          <forkMode>always</forkMode>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/TC_Integration*</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>**/TC_*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/TC_Unit*</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>**/TC_*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
```

What's the best way to make both run all the time?  I mainly want `maven install` to run both, but it's not.

Comment: What about `mvn verify`?

Comment: First using maven-failsafe-plugin as already suggested furthermore you should follow the naming conventions which are there this makes life easier...Unit Tests: `*Test.java*` integration tests `*IT.java`...and using as already mentioned by @chrylis using `mvn verify`otherwise the `post-integration-test` phase will not being executed which is sometimes needed for integration tests to shutdown things or cleanup etc.

Comment: I cannot change the test names.

Comment: Could you clarify current and expected behavior? I copied you code to my project and when I call `mvn install` both default-test and integration-test are launched

Comment: I think you're right, actually, I think what happens is that if there are failures in test it does not run the integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to configure surefire to run both unit and integration tests, configure surefire to run just the unit tests and use the failsafe plugin to run the integration tests.

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/